# Pushing repository to GitLab: RPC failed

Tags: git, nginx, tortoisegit

I have already set up the values for my client TortoiseGit:

```
git config --global http.postBuffer 1048576000
```

and also set up nginx on my server where GitLab is installed (/etc/nginx/nginx.conf):

```
client_max_body_size 1500m;
```

Making sure that after that I executed:

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

This is the output from TortoiseGIT when I try to push my files to an existing repository that I created first using my GitLab administration website:

```
Counting objects: 964, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (955/955), done.
Writing objects: 100% (964/964), 421.21 MiB | 14.45 MiB/s, done.
Total 964 (delta 426), reused 0 (delta 0)
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
error: RPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 413
Everything up-to-date
```

And then I check on my gitlab and I can see that my project is empty, nothing uploaded succesfully.

¿What else could be happening? I have been trying for hours to get this fixed and there is nothing else that comes to my mind. Thanks a lot.

Comment: FWIW : http status 413 indicates that the request entity is larger than the server is willing to process. Try segmenting your push ?

Comment: I have tried changing /etc/nginx/nginx.conf and the nginx that "comes" with GitLab installation: 
 /var/opt/gitlab/nginx/conf/nginx.conf

Comment: I am able to push all at the same time. Can't figure it out how to push only a certain folder

Comment: nobody can help me?? please!

Comment: my project takes 1.44GB. Maybe it is a GitLab limitation?

Comment: could be, cause the 'on the wire' push seems to complete, and it is at the back-end (gitlab) that the failure occurs (causing the 413).

Comment: I am sure about that. It must be the server configuration the one that is wrong. It must be something about where I place my client_max_body_size directive. Right now I have it in the HTTP context of this file: /etc/nginx/nginx.conf and I have it as well in the SERVER context in /etc/nginx/sites-available/gitlab

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into what appears to be an identical issue. I don't know if what you describe is treated the same or not but here's the steps I took that led to a successful 1GB repo push.

The first things I tried were like many others but listing here just in case it was a combined effort.

**Local Dev Computer:**

```
git config --global http.postBuffer 2097152000
```

I made this crazy high out of desperation. Tho.. I believe I read the max was around 500 MB or 200 MB. I don't recall.

**On Server Hosting GitLab:**

```
sudo gitlab-ctl deploy-page up

sudo vi /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb
```

I found this line in `gitlab.rb` file...

```
# nginx['client_max_body_size'] = '250m'
```

and changed it to...

```
nginx['client_max_body_size'] = '2048m'
```

My repo was a little over a 1 GB so I gave it some breathing room.

```
sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure

sudo gitlab-ctl deploy-page down
```

I then ran

```
git push -u origin master
```

Held my breath.

Then waited a little longer as it was longer than I could hold my breath.

Then Finally Success!!

This might not be the solution for you. But this worked out for me. Hopefully it can help someone.